# Maintaining State of the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, navigation, modal-dialog

I have a question on maintaining a state for entire component. (Let's consider I have one Modal component which take list and display it)

[image]

I have one Modal component. This component includes list with drill down arrow. On click of drilldown it will use same modal component with different data and this will go on until I have a data. Each modal component will also have a back button. Hence, when we click on back button it should lead to previously open modal. Also, here the route is not changing as I am working with modal pop up.

How to maintain state for the one modal component for different data?

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient is probably to translate or transform your date to an object, due to the nested structure of the lists' relationships.

You can also utilize React's [Context API](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext) if you need to store states that must be accessed by multiple different components.